# How to compile gallery and calendar css with grunt?

Tags: magento2, theme, less, grunt, compilation

I have put `gallery.less` and `calendar.css` in `web\mage\gallery` and `web\mage` respectively in my custom theme,  But they are not compile with `grunt`.

How can i compile these files with grunt like other modules and `web\css\source` less files ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please follow below step to compile **`"gallery.less"`**

1. create **"mage"** folder under your theme
2. copy **"gallery"** folder from **"root/lib/web/mage/gallery/"** and put under **"app/design/frontend/vendor(packagename)/your-theme(custom theme)/web/mage/"**
3. open **"root/dev/tools/grunt/configs/theme.js"** and put below code in it (configure your theme in **"theme.js"**)

   ```
   theme: {
   area: 'frontend',
   name: 'vendor/your-theme',
   locale: 'en_US',
   files: [
       'css/styles-m',
       'css/styles-l',
       'mage/gallery/gallery',
   ],
   dsl: 'less'
   ```

   }

please follow below step to compile **"calendar.css"**

1. create **"mage"** folder under your theme
2. cteate  **"calendar.less"** file under **("root/lib/web/mage/calendar.less")**  file.
3. copy all content from  **"root/lib/web/mage/calendar.css"** and put into file **"root/lib/web/mage/calendar.less"**
4. open **"root/dev/tools/grunt/configs/theme.js**" and put below code in it (configure your theme in **"theme.js"**).

**

```
theme: {
    area: 'frontend',
    name: 'vendor/your-theme',
    locale: 'en_US',
    files: [
        'css/styles-m',
        'css/styles-l',
        'mage/gallery/gallery',
        'mage/calendar',
    ],
    dsl: 'less'
}
```

**

1. clean **root/var/ and pub/static** folder
2. run grunt **exec:theme** (your-theme)
3. run **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**
4. run **grunt watch:theme** (your-theme)
5. modify "gallery.less", now it is compile through grunt